# How to use RegEx flags in PhpStorm's "Find and Replace"?

Tags: regex, phpstorm

When searching with a regex I want `.*` to match line separators (`\n`). To do it you should add `s` flag, but I can't quite figure out how to do it. Is there a way to add regex flags in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a DOTALL [inline modifier option](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall):

```
(?s).*
^^^^
```

This pattern means that all `.` to the right of the `(?s)` will also match line break chars.

> **Inline Modifier `(?s)`**
>   In .NET, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Perl, Python and Java (but not Ruby), you can use the inline modifier `(?s)`, for instance in `(?s)BEGIN .*? END`. See the section on [inline modifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers) for juicy details about three additional features (unavailable in Python): turning it on in mid-string, turning it off with `(?-s)`, or applying it only to the content of a non-capture group with `(?s:foo)`